# jQuery + VanillaJS achieve fastest selection method

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm developing an application with jQuery and i was wondering what is the fastest method to select an element with jQuery, there are hundreds of elements in this web page and each one has an unique id, and i'm doing this:

```
$("#main-container").addClass("col-lg-12");
```

i know that's the slowest approach to do it, so i think the main question is what is faster?

```
// 1
$("#main-container").addClass("col-lg-12");

// 2
$(document.getElementById("main-container")).addClass("col-lg-12");

// 3
$(document.querySelector("#main-container")).addClass("col-lg-12");
```

Comment: Given the similarity in performance of the 3 methods and that even the slowest runs several hundred thousand operations per second, choosing any of these for performance reasons is micro–optimisation. Use the one with the simplest, most maintainable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like http://jsperf.com/ for performance checks

Looks like `$(document.getElementById("main-container")).addClass("col-lg-12");` is the fastest of those 3

http://jsperf.com/buttsnanananannana/6

If you're pananoid about performance though, you probably shouldn't be using jQuery. You can do this instead: `document.getElementById('main-container').classList.add('col-lg-12')`

[image]

Comment: The "ugly" test is seriously flawed. What you have inadvertently shown is that by far the most expensive operation is creation of the jQuery object, and secondly calling the *addClass* method rather than assigning directly to the property.

Comment: @RobG Yes it is. But if you're worried about performance, that's the type of stuff you want to be looking at.

Comment: If the OP was genuinely worried about performance, he wouldn't be using jQuery.

Comment: @RobG xD yes, that's why I put a jQueryless example for him to see how much faster that is

Comment: Then the ugly one needs some explanation. ;-)

Comment: `document.getElementById('main-container').classList.add('col-lg-12');` is closer in behaviour to `addClass`

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett Nice, I didn't realize vanliia js had that. I updated the test to do that. It's very fast.

Comment: `document.getElementById('main-container').className+=' col-lg-12';` may be even faster, but it has the potential to add the class multiple times.  Because of that, the test above would have to be modified to clear the class names for each pass.  I'd go with Alfonso's suggestion, but would consider the browser implications.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really interested about performance you shoulnd't use jQuery. That said if you want to have the fastest selection method you should be using the most JavaScript native specific selection method you can, like:

```
document.getElementById()
document.getElementsByTagName()
document.getElementsByClassName()
```

I understand that it is really easy to use the most generic ones:

```
document.querySelector()
document.querySelectorAll()
```

The thing with the last ones is that they're going to spend time looking if your selector is a class or id, and/or if it's inside another elements.

However my recomendation for you is to use the specific ones every time you can, and if you want to use the jQuery thing and wrap them with it, well that is up to you.

There is a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/faster-selection) for you:

[image: specs]
[image: graphic]

As you can see in this chart, `document.getElementById()` is way faster than `document.querySelector()`. But when is wrapped into `$()` is like nine times slower than normal

Answer (score 0):

`$(document.getElementById("main-container")).addClass("col-lg-12");` will be the fastest selector out of the three that you've provided.